# Is polar coordinate right?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> Use polar coordinates to evaluate $$\iint_{D}^{} x \ dA$$where D is the region inside the circle, $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$  but outside the circle $x^2+y^2=1$

This what i have got so far:
$$A = \int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\int_1^{2 \sin\theta} r \cos\theta \,r \,dr \, d\theta$$

upon integrating I'm getting $0$.

Is the area correct?

Comment: Looks you took the opposite region, check once...

Comment: @ganeshie8 what do you mean by the opposite region?

Comment: you must get $0$ because the double integral refers to the x coordinate of center of mass of the given region. But it seems you took the opposite region, just double check your sketch... I think you should be working $$A = \int_{5\pi/6}^{13\pi/6}\int_{2sin\theta}^1 r \ cos\theta \ r \ dr \ d\theta$$

Comment: @ganeshie8 the region D is the region above the circle centre(0,0) and r =1 and below the circle centre(0,1) r= 1. So should be from $\pi/6 to 5\pi/6$ right?

Comment: [this green part](http://gyazo.com/323db86a327b777b516d4cfaa94dc0a9) is the region of integration right ?

Comment: @ganeshie8 no. its the top part. its outside the circle centre$ (0,0)$ but inside the circle $(0,1)$

Comment: then you're right!  there must be some typo in your question

Comment: I dont think so though,

Comment: read the highlighted parts in [this](http://gyazo.com/2f568e59bbd4e2514a64a408799e1068)

Comment: my mistake. i correct it. the question was wrong. my comment was right

Comment: its all good then ! $0$ is correct

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Convert the circle $ x^2+(y-1)^2=1 $ into polar coordinates: $ r = 2 \sin \theta , 0 < \theta < \pi. $

Comment: this what i did. then i $\int_{1}^{2sin\theta}$